# constructing an engine datalog file viewer, csv no loading data right

Tags: csv, scilab

Link to the source file at the bottom (no way to attach files?)

I am new to stack overflow, I've lurked for a while now but I need some help, I'm learning the layout still.

I am in need of building a program that can read and interpret engine data log files. I have only 1 choice for file format which is .csv. At work we all have access to excel, which is what I prefer due to its availability but I cannot get excel to operate correctly with any of the log files. The file I am using for example and help build this program has 69 columns and 84,715 rows, I simply want to pull out max and min values. Again, excel won't behave right, both max and min values are returned as the same value, I've tried several different methods to try and achieve this, no luck.

I'm resorting to using Scilab (because it's just like Matlab, but free and easier to justify its install at work). I have some experience using both scilab and matlab and I am fairly comfortable with them both. So I have changed the directory manually to the files location before running the code. So far I have:

```
dir // shows the directory 
data=uigetfile(["*.csv"]) // dialog window to select file
Data=csvRead("data",",",[],[],[],[],[],6) // reads file but skipped first 6 rows due to a header
(Usually a ; but modified to ,)
```

This is what I've got so far and so far not so good because once the csv is loaded,  it displays that variable Data is a 84,715 x 1 table

I have also tried just opening it in the console using:

```
csvRead("engine_log.csv",ascii(9),'string')
```

And I still end up getting a 84,715 x 1 array as well as 'NaN' in place of values.

I've even entered this directly into the console

```
csvRead("engine_log.csv",",",[],[],[],[],[],6) // reads file but skipped first 6 row
```

With no luck.

I've even made a little 4x5 csv to see if maybe it's the file I'm trying to use

```
csvRead("TEST 2.csv", ascii(9),'string') // csv loader

A.   B.   C.   D.   
1.   2.   3.   4.
2.   3.   4.   1.
3.   4.   1.   2.
4.   1.   2.   3.
```

Not quite sure where I went wrong or what I should do next

My end goal is to load these logfiles, any of them, pull out the max and min data of each pid.

In my experience (mostly sink or swim college programming classes), I have only had to do a csv read like, twice tops so I do believe I'm missing so key pieces. Any help would be great.  Sorry for such a long post.
[Link to csv file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am26MsR3p0_bw2ql7r9G-zrdnj8d)

Comment: Hi Ryan, MATLAB and Scilab, whilst sharing some syntax, are not the same. Consider [edit]ing to remove the MATLAB tag if this question doesn't directly relate to MATLAB, since answers using MATLAB functions (i.e. I'd use `readtable` here) will not be relevant. Ditto for the Excel tag, you either want a solution in Excel or you don't, manipulating csvs via Scilab doesn't seem to relate to Excel. We also don't really need to know most of the first 4 paragraphs, just "I have a csv file which looks like this: _____" so the question does not rely on external links would likely be as insightful

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Sorry for such a lengthy post, I was just unsure of what is relevant and what isn't, still learning about this community so I do apologize for that. I'll edit my post to remove the tags.

Answer (score 1):

In your linked file, the column separator is a semicolon ";" (not a tabulation). And since the file mixes strings and numbers, you should decide which type to load. If you read only numbers, empty and string cells will yield a Nan. For example, the first 10 lines of your file are read like this (strings then doubles):

```
--> M = csvRead("machin.csv", ";", [], [], [], [], [], 6)
 M  = 

         column 1 to 14

  "-1993"  "Closed"  ""      ""  ""      ""  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  "-1921"  ""        "0.00"  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  "-1900"  ""        ""      ""  "0.00"  ""  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  "-1808"  ""        ""      ""  ""      ""  ""  "0.08"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""

         column 15 to 33

  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""

         column 34 to 52

  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""

         column 53 to 68

  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  " "
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  " "
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0.00"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  " "
  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  " "

--> M = csvRead("machin.csv", ";", [], [], [], [], [], 6)
 M  = 

         column 1 to 12

  -1993.   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
  -1921.   Nan   0.    Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
  -1900.   Nan   Nan   Nan   0.    Nan   Nan   Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
  -1808.   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   0.08   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan

         column 13 to 25

   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan

         column 26 to 38

   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan

         column 39 to 51

   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan

         column 52 to 64

   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   0.    Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan

         column 65 to 68

   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
   Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
```

Comment: I forgot about the semi-colon being the separator, I knew that

Comment: So what ? `csvRead` succeeds to read your file no ?